# RabbitMQ one channel multiple consumers

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, amqp

I have node.js app, which has a rabbitmq consumer.
This consumer is craeted like this:

```
amqp.connect(RABBITMQ_URL, function (err, conn) {
    channel = conn.createChannel(function (err, ch) {
        var q = 'EXAMPLE_QUEUE';
        ch.prefetch(1, true);
        ch.assertQueue(q, { durable: true });

        ch.consume(q, (() => {
            // some logic
        }, {noAck: false})
    })
})
```

By scaling the app, I get multiple consumers active.
I want to have only one channel, so only one consumer will be active (only one unacked message for the channel). 
The 
`ch.prefetch(1, true)` should do that, but it do it per channel.
How can connect all the consumers under one channel? and if the channel doesnt exists, It will be created?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if publish-subscribe will be the right model for this. If I understood the question correctly, once consumer gets the message its gone for other consumers and they fetch next available message. Maybe what you're looking for is Work Queue and not Publish/Subscribe?

Comment: Hi. No. I have multiple users connected to my web app. The consumer has lot of messages waiting for some user to be available. Once available, the consumer performs an operation, and when the operation is finished, the messages is acked. By using multiple consumers, all I get is that when a user is available, all the consumers will perform the same operation, which has to be only once.